# Oracle Inner join - Select One row from right table

Tags: oracle

I have the following table layout

ACCIDENTS contains the accident ID
ACCIDENT_TO_CAR contains relations between accidents and car plates
REPORT contains the car plates  and driver names

Using the join below:

```
SELECT T_ACCIDENTS.ACCIDENT_ID,DRIVER_NAME
from T_ACCIDENTS
          inner join T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR on T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR.ACCIDENT_ID = T_ACCIDENTS.ACCIDENT_ID 
          inner join T_REPORT  on T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR.PLATE = T_REPORT.PLATE 
and DRIVER_NAME in ('Foo','Moo')
```

Currently Driver 'Foo' appears twice in the report because two of his cars had an accident.

How can limit the result of the join the driver by getting a single record ACCIDENT_TO_CAR
so in other words distinct on the report based on the driver

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE "T_ACCIDENTS" ("ACCIDENT_ID" VARCHAR2(20))

Insert into T_ACCIDENTS (ACCIDENT_ID) values ('1');
Insert into T_ACCIDENTS (ACCIDENT_ID) values ('2');
Insert into T_ACCIDENTS (ACCIDENT_ID) values ('3');



 CREATE TABLE "T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR" 
   (    
   "PLATE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "ACCIDENT_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) 

Insert into T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR (PLATE,ACCIDENT_ID) values ('1','1');
Insert into T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR (PLATE,ACCIDENT_ID) values ('2','1');
Insert into T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR (PLATE,ACCIDENT_ID) values ('4','2');
Insert into T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR (PLATE,ACCIDENT_ID) values ('3','1');
Insert into T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR (PLATE,ACCIDENT_ID) values ('2','2');



CREATE TABLE "T_REPORT" 
   (    
    "PLATE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "DRIVER_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   )

Insert into T_REPORT (PLATE,DRIVER_NAME) values ('1','Foo');
Insert into T_REPORT (PLATE,DRIVER_NAME) values ('2','Foo');
Insert into T_REPORT (PLATE,DRIVER_NAME) values ('3','Moo');
Insert into T_REPORT (PLATE,DRIVER_NAME) values ('4','Bar');
```

UPDATE
  I am sorry,the Data set and query was not correct, I fixed!

Comment: In your test data, two cars belonging to `Foo` were involved in the same accident.  If `Foo` had two separate accidents, I assume you would still want both of those listed (since you are including `accident_id` in your output?

Comment: i need Foo once per accident.

Comment: yes so 100 Foo and 200 Foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword to tell Oracle to only include unique records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T_ACCIDENTS.ACCIDENT_ID,T_REPORT.DRIVER_NAME
from T_ACCIDENTS
          inner join T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR on T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR.ACCIDENT_ID = T_ACCIDENTS.ACCIDENT_ID 
          inner join T_REPORT  on T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR.PLATE = T_REPORT.PLATE;
```

#### UPDATE BASED ON CLARIFIED REQUIREMENTS

`GROUP BY ACCIDENT_ID` and select the driver with the first name alphabetically.

```
SELECT T_ACCIDENTS.ACCIDENT_ID, MIN(DRIVER_NAME) DRIVER_NAME
from T_ACCIDENTS
          inner join T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR on T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR.ACCIDENT_ID = T_ACCIDENTS.ACCIDENT_ID 
          inner join T_REPORT  on T_ACCIDENT_TO_CAR.PLATE = T_REPORT.PLATE 
and DRIVER_NAME in ('Foo','Moo')
GROUP BY T_ACCIDENTS.ACCIDENT_ID;
```

Comment: Sorry, i fixed the test data see that the distinct is not working, this is exactly the issue.

Comment: I am confused.  Using `DISTINCT` with your updated test data gives: (1, Foo), (1, Moo), and (2, Foo).  Foo appears twice because Foo was involved in two separate accidents and you stated in comments that you want Foo to appear once for each accident.  So, what is wrong, exactly, with using `DISTINCT`?

Comment: I am getting (1,Moo),(1,Foo),(1,Foo),(2,Foo) without DISTINCT and  (1,Moo),(2,Foo)(1,Foo) with DISTINCT 
I would like to randomly select 1 (Foo or Moo) from the inner join like: (1,Moo),(2,Foo)  or (1,Foo),(2,Foo)  because i am after the accident ID, but still need one driver name.

Comment: So, you want one row per accident and the driver name to be any one of the drivers involved?